# Open file browser, select XML, parse fields using HTML/JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm able to launch a file-browser using an HTML Form + JQuery but am having a hard time getting past this point.  New to HTML, JQuery, JS.

Essentially, I have a series of existing, empty fields on our page that, after selecting an XML from the file-browser, need to wind up populated with information, parsed from the XML.

Just looking for more open, general direction and resources, haven't been able to find much on the subject.  Thanks!

Comment: two different parts. 1. file open js, 2.iterate and display XML js.

Comment: So what is the problem, using `new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');` to create an XML DOM document or using DOM methods like `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector`, `evaluate` to select nodes in the DOM document?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using an `input type="file"` element to read a selected `File` using `XMLHttpRequest` to get an XML DOM document to then populate the form elements with the data found in the XML:

```js
function loadData(fileInput) {
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', fileURL);
  req.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
    populateData(fileInput.form, this.responseXML);
  };
  req.onerror = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
    console.log('Error loading XML file.');
  };
  req.send();
}

function populateData(form, xmlDoc) {
  var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
  for (var i = 0, l = form.elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    var input = form.elements[i];
    if (input.name) {
      var xmlElement = root.querySelector(input.name);
      if (xmlElement) {
        input.value = xmlElement.textContent;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Select XML file to load data from:<input type="file" onchange="loadData(this);"></label>
  <br>
  <label>foo data
  <input type="text" name="foo"></label>
  <br>
  <label>bar data
  <input type="text" name="bar"></label>
 </form>
```

This assumes the XML document selected is a simple XML document with a root element of any name and child elements where the element name matches the input name in the HTML form, for instance

```
<data>
  <foo>foo data</foo>
  <bar>bar data</bar>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You should convert xml file to JSON. There are a lot of ways to do this. You can find open source suggestions, just google it. 
For example: https://code.google.com/p/x2js/.
When JSON will be got you can easy paste it into necessary fields.